# maven-war-plugin overlay only changed resources

Tags: maven, overlay, maven-war-plugin

I want to speed-up my maven assembly. In my project there are several modules which are merged to one web app using maven-war-plugin, but assembly takes much time, because every time maven-war-plugin overlays every module. So is there any way to make maven-war-plugin overlay only changed files?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [useCache](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#useCache) option. It's documented as an experimental feature, but it does make quite a difference for rebuilds with large war overlays.